# My .htaccess rewrite rule is NOT affecting subfolders and I wish it were

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to restrict direct access to images in directories while still letting those images appear on my pages.  (For example, I want my index.php to be able to use /images/example.jpg in its layout, but restrict directly typing http://foo.com/images/example.jpg into the browser.

I have this .htaccess code that does what I want, but only IF appears in each and every directory.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?foo.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?foo.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

**BUT, when this .htaccess is placed in the parent directory, it fails to affect the subdirectories.**  I have looked through many many posts, and almost all are trying to turn off .htaccess in subdirectories. This is the opposite problem.

I will eventually have thousands of subdirectories under the parent, and I don't want to have to place an .htaccess it in each.

It seems a crazy question, but how do I make this .htaccess rewrite rule work in all subdirectories too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like it should work as is. Are there _already_ .htaccess files with any rewrite rules in the subdirectories? Rules from the parent dir are not automatically inherited by default, but can be configured to.

Comment: I appreciate that it SHOULD work, but it only affects the directory it is in.  and no, there are not .htaccess files in the subdirectories

Comment: Do you have access to the server/virtualhost configuration? Are any RewriteRules defined there at the <VirtualHost> or <Directory> level? Those would also potentially interfere.

Comment: No and/or I don't think so... My cpanel has an "apache handlers" module...

Comment: If anyone was following this, here is/was the solution:  The .htaccess was indeed working, but once I had viewed the image in my web page, it became cached.  Subsequently, typing in the direct address "worked" but it was showing me the cached image.  And turning on features that forced refreshes did not work in this situation.  Only when I tried to access an image directly that I had not loaded through the webpage did I discover that this .htaccess was indeed working..  Thank you Michael for spending time trying to help me!

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't think of that. Browsers very aggressively cache redirects and response codes, so that is a common thing. I usually recommend trying it all out to debug with a completely fresh browser or incognito window.